# Intellectual Property rights

Tags: intellectual-property

Does the idea of using plastic for making roads and generating electricity using plastic, come under the intellectual Property Rights ?

How can one protect their product if it's not under the Intellectual Property Rights?

Comment: General ideas are not really a "protected concept", you need to refine it further into a patent or utility patent. You can publish research on the subject and claim copyright (which is a type of intellectual property right), but really products are not a protected item by themselves, you need to take action to do so (patent/trademark/etc). This also depends on what country you live in, mind sharing?

Comment: To be protected you would need to have a specific way of using plastic to make roads or electricity. You would also need a specific way of doing it to do it.

Answer (score 1):

### “Ideas” are not intellectual property

There are four types:

- **Copyright** protects artistic and literary works
- **Patent** protects practical inventions
- **Trademark** protects product identity
- **Registered design** protects product designs